# C function only definition return not expected?

Tags: c, gcc

The code below tries a simple action, compare float-point `1.0` with the return value of function `get_number`.

I only define the `get_number` function without declare, so that the return type of the function `get_number` is `int` not `double`, So the final output is `0` not `1`.

But if I declare function `get_number` in `func.h` file, it works fines.

Please help or try to give some ideas to explain it, thanks in advance.

### main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "func.h"

int main() {
    printf ("%d\n", 1.0 == get_number(1.0));

    return 0;
}
```

### func.c:

```
double get_number(double n) {
    return n;
}
```

### func.h:

```
#ifndef FUNC_H__
#define FUNC_H__

#endif
```

**Output**:

> 0

**NOTE:**
platform: Linux
gcc version: 4.8.5

Comment: This is not valid C! You have to declare functions before usage and your compiler should warn. (it was allowed until C99 which became standard 17 years ago). Don't use compilers which allow this (or compiler as C90/89 or K&R-C).

Comment: also: `__func__` is not an allowed name for a preprocessor macro. Names that start with an underscore are reserved.

Comment: I'm curious as to what thought process and decision tree led to you creating a logically empty header file and including it.

Comment: Actually, the similar issue arises in my project.The code above only to recurrence issue. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @Wine93: What??

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by others, it is no longer valid to omit the function declaration.

However, when you omit the declaration gcc will only emit a warning. Further gcc will assume that the function will return an `int`.

So when you run your program, the code in `main` expects the function to return an `int` but the function really returns a `double`. In other words, your code reads the `float` as if it is an `int`.

The following code illustrates what may happen when reading a `double` as if it was an `int` type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  double d;
  int i;

  printf ("---------------------------\n");

  d = 1.0; // represented as 0x3ff0000000000000
           //                                 ^
           //             The integer will be 0
  memcpy(&i, &d, sizeof(int));
  printf ("%d\n", i);

  printf ("---------------------------\n");

  d = 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625; // represented as 0x3ff0000000000001
                                                              //                                 ^
                                                              //             The integer will be 1
  memcpy(&i, &d, sizeof(int));
  printf ("%d\n", i);

  printf ("---------------------------\n");

  d = 1.000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125; // represented as 0x3ff0000000000002
                                                             //                                 ^
                                                             //             The integer will be 2
  memcpy(&i, &d, sizeof(int));
  printf ("%d\n", i);

  printf ("---------------------------\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---------------------------
0
---------------------------
1
---------------------------
2
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no function declaration only a function definition. Because of this, the compiler can't tell which function it should call. Since this is not allowed in "newer" standard your compiler should have warned you about that.

Also `#define __func_` as others have pointed out should not be used, since defines starting with underscores are preserved to the preprocessor .

First declare the function in a header (tell the compiler how the function is called):

```
#ifndef FUNC_H_
#define FUNC_H_

double get_number(double n);

#endif /* FUNC_H_ */
```

Then define it in your .c-file (so tell the compiler what the function does)

```
#include "func.h" // include the function declaration    

double get_number(double n)
{
  return n;
}
```

And now use it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func.h" // again include the function declaration

int main()
{
  printf("%f\n", get_number(1.0)); // use the function
}
```

Best practice is also to enable all warnings while compiling and if you want to be absolutly sure, there is nothing wrong with your program, also treat compiler warnings as errors

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -o myProgram main.c func.c

explained: 
-Wall   // enable all warnings
-Wextra // REALY enable all warnings
-Werror // treat all warnings as errors (so the program won't compile if there is any mistake)

-std=c11 // use the newest standard
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any compiler that actually warns on use of reserved-format names

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Really? Hmm. I thought GCC gave me a warning like this once but maybe I remember something incorrectly. Can't test it at the moment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Googled it and you're right. Apparently I must have redefinded a build in macro like `__FILE__` for which GCC actually produces a warning. But other than that it won't warn about these macros. Edited it

Comment: "There is no function declaration only a function definition."  Note that a function definition is also a function declaration.